# Usar DataTable en varias tablas en una sola página

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, datatables

En mi web con php, css y mysql tengo una página en la que muestro en varias tablas la info más importante de la bbdd.
Hasta ahora había usado Datatables en otras páginas con una sola tabla, pero ahora quiero implementarlo en cinco pequeñas tablas que alojo en una página.
Con el siguiente script, colocado al final del código me aparece bien la primera tabla, pero no el resto:

```
<script>
    var table=new DataTable('#myTable',{
        language:{
            url:'//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/2.0.2/i18n/es-ES.json',
        },
    });
    new DataTable('#myTable');
</script>
```

He pensado en colocarlo debajo de cada tabla, pero resultaría muy larga la página.
¿Hay alguna manera de que aparezca en todas las tablas y no haya que repetirlo hasta cinco veces?

Comment: Estás pasándole al constructor un ID, que son únicos. En html, css o JS, no puedes con un ID identificar más que un (1) elemento. Son únicos, se supone que no debe haber más. Te sugiero que modifiques ese `new DataTable('#myTable'...` por una clase, por ejemplo: `new DataTable('table.datatable-target'...`, y en las tablas en si mismas cambies el id por la clase `datatable-target` (puedes llamarle como quieras, pero USA CLASES Y NO IDS ÚNICOS PARA IDENTIFICAR COSAS QUE NO SON ÚNICAS!!!). Por cierto, por qué la creas dos veces seguidas? Una con configuración de idioma y una sin... no lo entiendo

Comment: Según indica en la web de Datatables, he cambieado: `new DataTable('table.display',{,` y hay dos tablas que aparecen correctas, pero en las otras tres no. Creo que tendré que poner el script debajo de cada tabla

Comment: te recomiendo que leas que es un ID y que es una CLASE y que son selectores en elementos HTML

Comment: Por fín lo arreglé.
No era problema de javasvript.
Era fallo mio de no cerrar bien las eiquetas tr de cuatro tablas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer los siguiente:

Obtienes todos los elementos `<table`> de la pagina y luego  creas las `datatable` dinamicamente

```html
<table id="2asda"></table>
<table id="3"></table>
<table id="4"></table>
<table id="5"></table>
<table id="6"></table>
<table id="7"></table>

<script>

    let elementos = document.getElementsByTagName("table");

    for (let index = 0; index < elementos.length; index++) {
        let element = elementos[index];

        new DataTable('#'+element.id,{
        language:{
            url:'//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/2.0.2/i18n/es-ES.json',
            },
        });

    }

</script>
```

Este código solo funciona: si quieres que todas las tablas de la pagina sean `datatables`.

Comment: La "a" del getElement no la entiendo, no me aparece en ninguna tabla lo que quiero. La he cambiado por "table" y lo he colocado al final de la página y me aparecen bien dos tablas, no las seis que temgo en la página.

Comment: perdón, error mío , he probado con <a> el código y he olvidado cambiar esa parte